# Physical file does not exist

Tags: sas

```
DATA hatco  ;
options ls=79;
options ps=60;

INFILE '~dscbms/class/dsc8450/files/hatco';
     INPUT X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14;
LABEL X1='DELIVERY SPEED'
       X2='PRICE LEVEL'
       X3='PRICE FLEXIBILITY'
       X4='MANUFACTURER IMAGE'
       X5='OVERALL SERVICE'
       X6='SALES FORCE IMAGE'
       X7='PRODUCT QUALITY'
       X8='SIZE OF FIRM'
       X9='USAGE LEVEL'
       X10='SATISFACTION LEVEL'
       X11='SPECIFICATION BUYING'
       X12='STRUCTURE OF PROCUREMENT'
       X13='TYPE OF INDUSTRY'
       X14='TYPE OF BUYING SITUATION';
Proc means;
        var x1-x14;
PROC UNIVARIATE PLOT NORMAL;
        var x1-x7 x9;
```

Im trying to run this programe in SAS but i got error

```
ERROR: Physical file does not exist,
       D:\Backups\SAS\~dscbms\class\dsc8450\files\hatco.
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
WARNING: The data set WORK.HATCO may be incomplete.  When this step was
         stopped there were 0 observations and 14 variables.
WARNING: Data set WORK.HATCO was not replaced because this step was stopped.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds
```

please help me thankx in advance

Answer (score 2):

Is your SAS installation running on your local (Windows) machine?
And you try to access a file on a Unix machine?
Use an appropriate filename statement.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file with xyz.txt having values then give the proper path of that file in the SAS inline code like that : Your sas code will be this

```
DATA hatco  ;
options ls=79;
options ps=60;

INFILE 'D:/test.txt';
     INPUT X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14;
LABEL X1='DELIVERY SPEED'
       X2='PRICE LEVEL'
       X3='PRICE FLEXIBILITY'
       X4='MANUFACTURER IMAGE'
       X5='OVERALL SERVICE'
       X6='SALES FORCE IMAGE'
       X7='PRODUCT QUALITY'
       X8='SIZE OF FIRM'
       X9='USAGE LEVEL'
       X10='SATISFACTION LEVEL'
       X11='SPECIFICATION BUYING'
       X12='STRUCTURE OF PROCUREMENT'
       X13='TYPE OF INDUSTRY'
       X14='TYPE OF BUYING SITUATION';
Proc means;
        var x1-x14;
PROC UNIVARIATE PLOT NORMAL;
        var x1-x7 x9;
```

and xyz.txt file like that

```
X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9   10  11  12  13  14
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9   10  11  12  13  14
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9   10  11  12  13  14
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9   10  11  12  13  14
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9   10  11  12  13  14
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9   10  11  12  13  14
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9   10  11  12  13  14
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9   10  11  12  13  14
```

There is only issue with in your file path from which you are getting data or setting.